# Kivy > Threading and using the Spinner

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I am struggling to understand how I can get the Spinner to activate before running a long process and then to deactivate it.

Below is an example. I tried in the KV file to run run the method to toggle the spinner and then run the threaded process and then to deactivate it but that didn't work.  I then added the mainthread decorator to the toggle spinner method and ran that before the threaded process but that didn't work either.

```
from kivy.clock import mainthread
from kivy.lang import Builder
import threading

from kivymd.app import MDApp

KV = '''
#: import threading threading
Screen:
    BoxLayout:
        MDSpinner:
            id: spinner
            size_hint: None, None
            size: dp(46), dp(46)
            pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}
            active: True if check.active else False
    
        MDCheckbox:
            id: check
            size_hint: None, None
            size: dp(48), dp(48)
            pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .4}
            active: True
        
        Button:
            text: 'Spinner On/Off'
            size_hint: None, None
            size: dp(150), dp(150)
            on_release: app.spinner_toggle()
        
        Button:
            text: 'Run Long Process'
            size_hint: None, None
            size: dp(150), dp(150)
            on_release: 
                app.spinner_toggle()
                app.long_process_thread()
                app.spinner_toggle()
'''


class Test(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)

    @mainthread
    def spinner_toggle(self):
        print('Spinner Toggle')
        app = self.get_running_app()
        if app.root.ids.spinner.active == False:
            app.root.ids.spinner.active = True
        else:
            app.root.ids.spinner.active = False


    def long_process(self):
        for x in range(1000000):
            print(x)

    def long_process_thread(self):
        self.spinner_toggle()
        threading.Thread(target=(self.long_process())).start()
        self.spinner_toggle()



Test().run()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple problems. The first is your line:

```
threading.Thread(target=(self.long_process())).start()
```

In that call the code `self.long_process()` is actually running `long_process()` before starting the thread. You actually want to do:

```
threading.Thread(target=(self.long_process)).start()
```

Notice the lack of `()`.

The second problem is that you are calling `self.spinner_toggle()` immediately  after starting the thread, so the `Spinner` is toggled again long before the thread finishes. To fix that, you can call `self.spinner_toggle()` at the end of the thread. So, here is a part of your code with those modifications:

```
def long_process(self):
    for x in range(1000000):
        print(x)
    self.spinner_toggle()

def long_process_thread(self):
    self.spinner_toggle()
    threading.Thread(target=(self.long_process)).start()
```

By the way, in your `kv` you can replace:

```
active: True if check.active else False
```

with the simpler:

```
active: check.active
```